# how to implement the google-api-client-1.7.0 in java

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to implement the google places API in a Java application. I followed the steps  mentioned in http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html. I have the Java client library google-api-client-1.7.0-beta.jar. Could anyone tell me how to implement the client library in Java project. I am using the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:
Right click on the project -> Build Path -> Add External Archives -> type path to your jar.